# Can't update defaultValue with onChange React.js Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

I'm making a dynamically rendered form using map and I update all the values into a dictionary. However, once I update the values, I storage them into Firebase and when I submit the form, I need to display what I storage as the input default values.

```
  const [local, setLocal] = useState([]);
  const [visitante, setVisitante] = useState([]);

 const handleChangeLocal = (e, i) => {
    const { value, name } = e.target;

    const newState = [...local];
    newState[i] = {
      ...newState[i],
      [name]: value,
    };
    setLocal(newState);
  };

  const handleChangeVisitante = (e, i) => {
    const { value, name } = e.target;

    const newState = [...visitante];
    newState[i] = {
      ...newState[i],
      [name]: value,
    };

    setVisitante(newState);
  };



// FIREBASE

const resultados = {};

  for (let i = 1; i < local.length; i++) {
    resultados[i] = { local: local[i], visitante: visitante[i] };
  }

  async function saveResults() {
    const decodedToken = await firebase.auth().currentUser?.getIdTokenResult();
    const uid = decodedToken?.claims?.user_id;
    const db = firebase.firestore();

    const quiniela = db
      .collection("users")
      .doc(uid)
      .collection("pool")
      .doc("results");

    quiniela.set({
      resultados: resultados,
    });
    router.push(`/quiniela/${uid}`);
  }
```

```
<input
                          id={i}
                          type="number"
                          defaultValue={
                            userData[partido["partido"]].local[
                              partido["HomeTeam"]
                            ]
                          }
                          className="w-12 border -ml-8 text-center"
                          placeholder="#"
                          name={partido["HomeTeam"]}
                          required
                          step={1}
                          min={0}
                          max={20}
                          onChange={(e) =>
                            handleChangeLocal(e, partido["partido"])
                          }
                        />

 <input
                          id={i}
                          type="number"
                          className="w-12 border ml-20  text-center"
                          placeholder="#"
                          defaultValue={
                            userData[partido["partido"]].visitante[
                              partido["AwayTeam"]
                            ]
                          }
                          name={partido["AwayTeam"]}
                          step={1}
                          min={0}
                          max={20}
                          onChange={(e) =>
                            handleChangeVisitante(e, partido["partido"])
                          }
                          required
                        />
```

It works when I submit data for the first time, however, onChange doesn't work once I set the defaultValues from Firebase.

[image]

What's going on? Or what should I change?

Answer (score 0):

Because defaultValue cannot be updated.

Use value instead

```
value={
  userData[partido["partido"]].local[
    partido["HomeTeam"]
  ]
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but when I use value, I can´t modify the inputs. How can I use value, and still be able to modify the inputs?

Comment: It means that your `onChange` function is not working correctly

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have no idea what `userData` is, but I guess that you wanted to use `local[partido["partido"]]` for the `value` because that's what you set in `onChange`

Comment: onChange={(e) =>handleChangeLocal(e, partido["partido"]) }, returns a number, and I use that number as an index in:                                                                               
const handleChangeLocal = (e, i) => {
    const { value, name } = e.target;

    const newState = [...local];
    newState[i] = {
      ...newState[i],
      [name]: value,
    };
    setLocal(newState);
  };